# Why I cannot push my code to github?

Tags: git, github

```
$git push origin master
To git@github.com:dimitar9/first_app.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:%USERNAME/first_app.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: thank you hammar and Wes, but how can to ignore all remote changes? I just want to push my local version forcely. can i do this?

Comment: You can't. The remote server is configured for "fast forward updates only". There are two ways to resolve this. Either (a) do what hammar and Wes are suggesting, or (b) push to a new branch.

Comment: Actually, you can, but you shouldn't: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that there are some changes on GitHub which have not been merged into your current branch. To resolve this, do what the error message is telling you to: `git pull`, resolve any conflicts, then try pushing again.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do a `git pull` first.

**Update with explanation**: Because you don't have the latest code, git forces you to do the merge on your side before pushing changes. This is to help prevent losing changes other people have made.

If you have any conflicts, you should review them to decide whether the local or remote code is what you want to commit.