# Can't install jekyll-bootstrap on my github site

Tags: git, github

so I cloned jekyll-boostrap and tried to push to my anthonybrown.github.com and got this message:

```
t67:anthonybrown.github.com anthonybrown$ git remote add origin
git@github.com:anthonybrown/anthonybrown.github.com.git fatal: remote origin already exists.
t67:anthonybrown.github.com anthonybrown$ git push origin master
To git@github.com:anthonybrown/anthonybrown.github.com.git
 ! [rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:anthonybrown/anthonybrown.github.com.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again. See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
t67:anthonybrown.github.com anthonybrown$ git push --help
```

What am I doing wrong ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I cannot push my code to github?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775399/why-i-cannot-push-my-code-to-github)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out a while back, learn git first, working with git pages is easy