# Github Rejected

Tags: git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why I cannot push my code to github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775399/why-i-cannot-push-my-code-to-github)

I am trying to push origin master to git hub and I keep getting rejected, it prompts me for a username and password and I am sure it is correct.

This is the error I am getting

```
To https://github.com/anderskitson/omrails.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/anderskitson/omrails.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do

```
git pull
```

then you can do

```
git push
```

The reason why you are getting rejected, is because on the server there are commits that you don't have locally, so you need to merge them before to push.

Same thing happens with subversion: you need to `svn up` before doing `svn commit`.

Answer (score 1):

Make a pull. Your remote branch is before your local branch.

`git pull`

Answer (score 1):

There are some commits on github that you don't have on your local repository. Pushing your changes will replace the changes that are already up on github, and those commits will be lost.

The solution is to pull in the github changes and merge them on your local repository, then you can push your changes to github without worrying about losing those changes.

The way you solve this is by running:

```
git pull
```

If the command notifies you of any conflicts, fix them, then add and commit the merged files. Most of the time you won't encounter any conflicts, so you don't have to do anything here.

Then try pushing again:

```
git push
```